# Using SSL Certificates on Netty

Tags: ssl, netty

I'm trying to build a simple client-server application using Netty which uses SSL certificates .

I looked around and I could only find the secure chat example [[here](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html)]. It uses bogus certificates.

How to do a proper implementation of SSL certificates (self-signed) in Netty?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against self signed certificates. It's not worth the trouble. You can get signed certificate for free from [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/). Check out the link below on how to convert a signed certificate into PKCS12 format and use it in SSLContext to be used with Netty.

http://blog.hintcafe.com/post/33709433256/https-server-in-java-using-netty-and-keystore